# How to retrieve the list of all GitHub repositories of a person?

Tags: github, github-api

We need to display all the projects of a person in his repository on GitHub account.

How can I display the names of all the git repositories of a particular person using his git-user name?

Answer (score 122):

You can use the [github api](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/) for this. Hitting `https://api.github.com/users/USERNAME/repos` will list public repositories for the user *USERNAME*.

Comment: you can also chose how much repos you get with `?per_page=` https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination

Comment: https://api.github.com/users/USERNAME/repos?page=1 gives first page of results. (change 1 to 2 and so on, default is 30 results per page)

Comment: that is a repository, not a project

Answer (score 48):

Use the [Github API](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/):

`/users/:user/repos`

This will give you all the user's public repositories. If you need to find out private repositories you will need to authenticate as the particular user. You can then use the REST call:

`/user/repos`

to find *all* the user's repos.

To do this in Python do something like:

```
USER='AUSER'
API_TOKEN='ATOKEN'
GIT_API_URL='https://api.github.com'

def get_api(url):
    try:
        request = urllib2.Request(GIT_API_URL + url)
        base64string = base64.encodestring('%s/token:%s' % (USER, API_TOKEN)).replace('\n', '')
        request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
        result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
        result.close()
    except:
        print 'Failed to get api request from %s' % url
```

Where the url passed in to the function is the REST url as in the examples above. If you don't need to authenticate then simply modify the method to remove adding the Authorization header. You can then get any public api url using a simple GET request.

Comment: This will only give the first "page" of the result set, which is set at 30 items by default. You can use `?per_page=100` to get the maximum ammount but if a user has more than a hundred repos you will need to follow several `next` URLs in the HTTP `Link` header send with the response.

Answer (score 45):

Try the following `curl` command to list the repositories:

```
GHUSER=CHANGEME; curl "https://api.github.com/users/$GHUSER/repos?per_page=100" | grep -o 'git@[^"]*'
```

To list cloned URLs, run:

```
GHUSER=CHANGEME; curl -s "https://api.github.com/users/$GHUSER/repos?per_page=1000" | grep -w clone_url | grep -o '[^"]\+://.\+.git'
```

If it's private, you need to add your API key (`access_token=GITHUB_API_TOKEN`), for example:

```
curl "https://api.github.com/users/$GHUSER/repos?access_token=$GITHUB_API_TOKEN" | grep -w clone_url
```

If the user is organisation, use `/orgs/:username/repos` instead, to return all repositories.

To clone them, see: [How to clone all repos at once from GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19576742/55075)

See also: [How to download GitHub Release from private repo using command line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20396329/55075)

Comment: This shows only the first 100 repositories, regardless of the `per_page=1000`.

Comment: Add the `-s` option to your `curl` command to get rid of those unsightly progress bars, as in `curl -s ...`

Comment: As @jm666 says, the maximum page size is 100. To see the 2nd page, do: curl "https://api.github.com/users/$USER/repos?per_page=100\&page=2"

Comment: The private example won't work with the example, /users/ "in plural" only returns public repos. You need to go with https://api.github.com/user/repos and add the token into the request to get private ones.

Comment: @LeandroCR For private repos, see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35688093/55075).

Comment: I used this solution and added some CLI-fu at the end to get a bare list with just the names of the repos without the `git@github.com:USERNAME/` that proceeds it and  the `.git` that trails it:  

`GHUSER=CHANGEME; curl -s "https://api.github.com/users/$GHUSER/repos?per_page=100" | grep -o 'git@[^"]*' | cut -d/ -f 2 | cut -d. -f 1`

Comment: I have 200+ repos when I see it in GitHub web, this command only downloads 70+, why is that? Is it because some repos are restricted access? can I pass a token with the command to let it see the same thing I see in the web?

Comment: @ioslearner Maybe they're private? Then check the link related to private repos.

Comment: @kenorb mystery solved, the user is an org so `/orgs/:username/repos` return all the repos,  `/users/...` return part of them, this is indeed weird. the username can be treated as both an user or an org.

Comment: Using the `access_token` query parameter is deprecated. Use the Authorization HTTP header instead.

Comment: @ioslearner: not sure about certain few users, but users in general are not orgs. https://api.github.com/users/andrew/repos works but https://api.github.com/orgs/andrew/repos doesn't work. Is there a solution to download all repositories description with a single command? Because at this moment it only shows the first 100, regardless of the "per_page=1000"

Answer (score 19):

### Using the `gh` command

You can use the [github cli](https://github.com/cli/cli) for this:

```bash
gh api users/:owner/repos
```

or

```
gh api orgs/:orgname/repos
```

For all the repos you'll want `--paginate` and you can combine this with `--jq` to show only `name` for each repo:

```
gh api orgs/:orgname/repos --paginate  --jq '.[].name' | sort
```

Answer (score 15):

Here is a full spec for the repos API:

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-repositories-for-a-user

`GET /users/:username/repos`

Query String Parameters:

The first 5 are documented in the API link above. The parameters for `page` and `per_page` are documented elsewhere and are useful in a full description.

- `type` (string): Can be one of `all`, `owner`, `member`. Default: `owner`
- `sort` (string): Can be one of `created`, `updated`, `pushed`, `full_name`. Default: `full_name`
- `direction` (string): Can be one of `asc` or `desc`. Default: `asc` when using `full_name`, otherwise `desc`
- `page` (integer): Current page
- `per_page` (integer): number of records per page

Since this is an HTTP GET API, in addition to cURL, you can try this out simply in the browser. For example:

https://api.github.com/users/grokify/repos?per_page=2&page=2

Comment: Thanks for capturing this. The API docs have changed and now neither of https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#list-repositories-for-the-authenticated-user and your link actually display the possible values of "type".

Answer (score 12):

If you have [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) installed, you can use the following command to list all public repos of a user

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/users/<username>/repos | jq '.[]|.html_url'
```

Answer (score 8):

You probably need a jsonp solution:

`https://api.github.com/users/[user name]/repos?callback=abc`

If you use jQuery:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "https://api.github.com/users/blackmiaool/repos",
  jsonp: true,
  method: "GET",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(res) {
    console.log(res)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 6):

The NPM module [repos](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/repos) grabs the JSON for all public repos for some user or group. You can run this directly from `npx` so you don't need to install anything just pick an org or user ("W3C" here):

```sh
$ npx repos W3C W3Crepos.json
```

This will create a file called W3Crepos.json. Grep is good enough to e.g. fetch the list of repos:

```sh
$ grep full_name W3Crepos.json
```

pros:

- Works with more than 100 repos (many answers to this question don't).
- Not much to type.

cons:

- Requires `npx` (or `npm` if you want to install it for real).

Answer (score 6):

There's now an option to use the awesome [GraphQL API Explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/).

I wanted a list of all my org's active repos with their respective languages. This query does just that:

```
{
  organization(login: "ORG_NAME") {
    repositories(isFork: false, first: 100, orderBy: {field: UPDATED_AT, direction: DESC}) {
      pageInfo {
        endCursor
      }
      nodes {
        name
        updatedAt
        languages(first: 5, orderBy: {field: SIZE, direction: DESC}) {
          nodes {
            name
          }
        }
        primaryLanguage {
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Retrieve the list of all public repositories of a GitHub user using Python:

```py
import requests
username = input("Enter the github username:")
request = requests.get('https://api.github.com/users/'+username+'/repos')
json = request.json()
for i in range(0,len(json)):
  print("Project Number:",i+1)
  print("Project Name:",json[i]['name'])
  print("Project URL:",json[i]['svn_url'],"\n")
```

[Reference](https://github.com/darshanc99/Python-Scraps-WT-purpose-/blob/master/git.py)

Comment: this not working  (maybe it's for older api version)

Comment: yes, there is a small change. I have edited my answer, and now it works well.

Answer (score 5):

If looking for repos of an organisation-

api.github.com/orgs/$NAMEOFORG/repos

Example:

```
curl https://api.github.com/orgs/arduino-libraries/repos
```

Also you can add the per_page parameter to get all names just in case there is a pagination problem-

```
curl https://api.github.com/orgs/arduino-libraries/repos?per_page=100
```

Answer (score 3):

## Using Python

```py
import requests

link = ('https://api.github.com/users/{USERNAME}/repos')

api_link = requests.get(link)
api_data = api_link.json()

repos_Data = (api_data)

repos = []

[print(f"- {items['name']}") for items in repos_Data]
```

If you want to get all the repositories in a list (array) you could do something like this:

```py
import requests

link = ('https://api.github.com/users/{USERNAME}/repos')

api_link = requests.get(link)
api_data = api_link.json()

repos_Data = (api_data)

repos = []

[repos.append(items['name']) for items in repos_Data]
```

This will store all the repositories in the "repos" array.

Answer (score 2):

## Paging JSON

The JS code below is meant to be used in a console.

```
username = "mathieucaroff";

w = window;
Promise.all(Array.from(Array(Math.ceil(1+184/30)).keys()).map(p =>
    fetch(`//api.github.com/users/{username}/repos?page=${p}`).then(r => r.json())
)).then(all => {
    w.jo = [].concat(...all);
    // w.jo.sort();
    // w.jof = w.jo.map(x => x.forks);
    // w.jow = w.jo.map(x => x.watchers)
})
```

Answer (score 2):

**HTML**

```
<div class="repositories"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

// Github repos

If you wanted to limit the repositories list, you can just add `?per_page=3` after `username/repos`.

e.g `username/repos?per_page=3`

Instead of /`username`/, you can put any person's username on Github.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET','https://api.github.com/users/username/repos' , 
        true)
        request.onload = function() {
            var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
            console.log(data);
            var statusHTML = '';
            $.each(data, function(i, status){
                statusHTML += '<div class="card"> \
                <a href=""> \
                    <h4>' + status.name +  '</h4> \
                    <div class="state"> \
                        <span class="mr-4"><i class="fa fa-star mr-2"></i>' + status.stargazers_count +  '</span> \
                        <span class="mr-4"><i class="fa fa-code-fork mr-2"></i>' + status.forks_count + '</span> \
                    </div> \
                </a> \
            </div>';
            });
            $('.repositories').html(statusHTML);
        }
        request.send();
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "/users/:user/repo", but I have all the code that does this in an open-source project that you can use to stand up a web-application on a server.

I stood up a GitHub project called [Git-Captain](https://github.com/ConfusedDeer/Git-Captain) that communicates with the GitHub API that lists all the repos.

It's an open-source web-application built with Node.js utilizing GitHub API to find, create, and delete a branch throughout numerous GitHub repositories.

It can be setup for organizations or a single user.

I have a step-by-step how to set it up as well in the read-me.

Answer (score 1):

To get the user's 100 public repositories's url:

```js
$.getJSON("https://api.github.com/users/suhailvs/repos?per_page=100", function(json) {
  var resp = '';
  $.each(json, function(index, value) {
    resp=resp+index + ' ' + value['html_url']+ ' -';
    console.log(resp);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const request = require('request');
const config = require('config');

router.get('/github/:username', (req, res) => {
    try {
        const options = {

            uri: `https://api.github.com/users/${req.params.username}/repos?per_page=5
                 &sort=created:asc
                 &client_id=${config.get('githubClientId')}
                 &client_secret=${config.get('githubSecret')}`,

            method: 'GET',

            headers: { 'user-agent': 'node.js' }
        };
        request(options, (error, response, body) => {
            if (error) console.log(error);
            if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
                res.status(404).json({ msg: 'No Github profile found.' })
            }
            res.json(JSON.parse(body));
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
        res.status(500).send('Server Error!');
    }
});
```

Comment: for more details visit git docs-> https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) before posting... When you post an answer and there are some more, show the Pros of your POV and, please, don´t just post code, explain it a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

## Using Javascript Fetch

```js
async function getUserRepos(username) {
   const repos = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${username}/repos`);
   return repos;
}

getUserRepos("[USERNAME]")
      .then(repos => {
           console.log(repos);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly improved version of @joelazar's answer to get as a cleaned list:

```
gh repo list <owner> -L 400 |awk '{print $1}' |sed "s/<owner>\///"
```

Replace  with the owner name, of course.

This can get lists with >100 repos as well (in this case, 400)

Answer (score 1):

## Paging Bash

Paste your token in a file called `github_token_file` and give it permissions `0400`.

```bash
GITHUB_TOKEN=$(cat github_token_file)
USER=myuser

page=1
while : ; do
    echo Page $page
    result=$(curl --header "authorization: Bearer $GITHUB_TOKEN" "https://api.github.com/user/repos?per_page=100&page=$page")
    echo $result | jq '.[].name' | sort
    wc=$(echo $result | wc -w)
    [[ $wc -lt "10" ]] && break || true
    page=$((page+1))
done
```

Note that by using `/users/<username>/repos` you are hitting the public repos only, while `/user/repos` is hitting both public and private.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [official GitHub command-line tool](https://github.com/cli/cli):

```
gh auth login

gh api graphql --paginate -f query='
query($endCursor: String) {
    viewer {
    repositories(first: 100, after: $endCursor) {
        nodes { nameWithOwner }
        pageInfo {
        hasNextPage
        endCursor
        }
    }
    }
}
' | jq ".[] | .viewer | .repositories | .nodes | .[] | .nameWithOwner"
```

**Note**: this will include all of your public, private and other people's repos that are shared with you.

References:

- https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_api

Answer (score 0):

And in case you want to list repo names filtered by specific topic:

```
gh search repos --owner=<org> --topic=payments --json name --jq ".[].name" --limit 200
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit more memorable (simplified) versions of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33159888/9962007) answer (upvoted) to get **public** repos (only):

```
# quick way to get all (up to 100) public repos for user mirekphd
$ curl -s "https://api.github.com/users/mirekphd/repos?per_page=100" | grep full_name | sort
```

The *current* method to get *all* (up to 100) **private** repos from Github API (see [docs](https://github.community/t/how-to-get-list-of-private-repositories-via-api-call/120175) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63720399/9962007) answer):

```
# get all private repos from the Github API 
# after logging with Personal Access Token (assuming secure 2FA is used)
$ export GITHUB_USER=mirekphd && export GITHUB_TOKEN=$(cat <path_redacted>/personal-github-token) && curl -s --header "Authorization: Bearer $GITHUB_TOKEN" --request GET "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=user:$GITHUB_USER&per_page=100" | grep "full_name" | sort
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do it in postman.
This way you can visualize it, run scripts, etc.

Check it out.

https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/visualizer/

[image]

[image]