# How can I find all public repos in github that a user contributes to?

Tags: python, github3.py

I'm using the [github3 python library](http://github3py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and am trying to find all public repos that users from our organization have contributed to (to reward the support of open source!).
I've got the list of users for the organization, but now what?
Can I use the public events iterator to find repos?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import argparse
import github3


def get_organization(github, name):
    for organization in github.iter_orgs():
        if organization.login == name:
            return organization


def main(args):
    github = github3.login(args.github_username, password=args.github_password)
    organization = get_organization(github, args.organization)

    # Get a list of all current organization contributors
    orgMembers = [member.login for member in organization.iter_members()]

# now what?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take an example [of test_github.py](https://github.com/sigmavirus24/github3.py/blob/c0af354c3578c9680c691e01e3e696facbc07ad7/tests/test_github.py#L493-L506):

```
def test_iter_user_repos(self):
    self.response('repo', _iter=True)
    self.get('https://api.github.com/users/sigmavirus24/repos')
    self.conf.update(params={'type': 'all', 'direction': 'desc'})

    next(self.g.iter_user_repos('sigmavirus24', 'all', direction='desc'))
    self.mock_assertions()

    self.conf.update(params={"sort": "created"})
    self.get('https://api.github.com/users/sigmavirus24/repos')

    assert isinstance(next(self.g.iter_user_repos('sigmavirus24', sort="created")),
                      github3.repos.Repository)
    self.mock_assertions()
```

It is based on the [GitHub API](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-user-repositories) mentioned in "[How to retrieve the list of all github repositories of a person?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8713716/6309)":

```
/users/:user/repos
```

(public repos only)