# Can github3.py be used to find the parent/upstream of a forked repo?

Tags: python, git-fork, github3.py

Given a forked repo, how can I use github3.py to find the parent or upstream repo that it was forked from?  This is fairly easy with **requests** but I can not figure out how to do it in github3.py.

With requests:

```
for repo in gh.repositories_by(username):  # github3.py provides a user's repos
  if repo.fork:                            # we only care about forked repos
    assert 'parent' not in repo.as_dict()  # can't find parent using github3.py
    repo_info = requests.get(repo.url).json()  # try with requests instead
    assert 'parent' in repo_info, repo_info    # can find parent using requests
    print(f'{repo_info["url"]} was forked from {repo_info["parent"]["url"]}')
    # https://github.com/username/repo was forked from
    # https://github.com/parent/repo
```

This use case is similar to [How can I find all public repos in github that a user contributes to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18711121/how-can-i-find-all-public-repos-in-github-that-a-user-contributes-to) but we also need to check the parent/upstream repo that the user's repo was forked from.

Comment: Have you got any code at all that uses `github3.py`? It might be useful to see your starting point. (Plus please format your code properly. Python is very sensitive to indentation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation shows that this is stored as [repo.parent](https://github3.readthedocs.io/en/develop/api-reference/repos.html#github3.repos.repo.Repository.parent), that however, is only available on `Repository` objects. `repositories_by` returns `ShortRepository` objects.

This would look like:

```
for short_repo in gh.repositories_by(username):
    repo = short_repo.refresh()
    if repo.fork:
        parent = repo.parent
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks.  I thought that __repo.refresh()__ would modify __repo__ but I needed to do __repo = repo.refresh()__.  Thanks for your answer and all your efforts on __github3.py__.