# cloning all github repositories on a personal account

Tags: git

I've been searching around and discovered several topics about this that use a lot of various technologies like `ruby` and some `bash` scripts - but basically, I have a normal, plain github account and I want to "clean" it. But there is code on there I *may* want to keep, so I don't want to just destroy it all. Furthermore, there are almost 200 repos.

So I want to just clone them all to my hard drive, then back them up to a dummy account like bitbucket. I'm having a tough time with this though.

Is there a simple way to accomplish this? I'm using Windows 8, and my experience with command line tools is extremely minimal right now.

Comment: Sounds like a job for the command line! Have a look at MySysGit (http://stackoverflow.com/a/28519524) and then http://stackoverflow.com/q/19576742.

Comment: I did try that one, actually, but it didn't work for me. It seemed to expect a company account, which I don't have.

Comment: The second one, I mean.

Comment: The comments below the accepted answer seem to clear some of that up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a solution involving command line tools.  If this doesn't meet your immediate needs, maybe someone else will find it helpful.

First, here's a script that will produce a list (on *stdout*) of all your GitHub repositories:

- https://github.com/larsks/github-tools/blob/master/repolist.py

You can authenticate using either a username and password or a personal API token.  You can take the output of this command and feed it to a simple shell loop to clone all the repositories:

```
./repolist.py -t my_access_token |
while read url; do
  git clone $url
done
```

Go grab a coffee (or something more substantial, if you have a lot of
data to clone), and when you come back you should have a local copy of
everything.

Comment: I didn't want to get Python, but I had no choice. This did not disappoint, either. This has made me interested in python as a language, and it solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a tool like [GitHub Archive](https://github.com/Justintime50/github-archive) which allows you to clone/pull public and private personal repos, organization repos, and gists all with one simple tool.

As for automation, you could then set up GitHub Archive to run once a day or once a week for example and it will skip those that are cloned and pull in new changes since the last time it was run of all others.

GitHub Project: https://github.com/Justintime50/github-archive