# GitHub: How to do case sensitive search for the code in repository?

Tags: git, github, version-control, open-source, case-sensitive

I want to do a case sensitive search for a particular piece of code in a GitHub repository. Is it possible?

I checked https://help.github.com/articles/searching-code/ and didn't find such a syntax rule.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use `grep` or `git grep` in your local clone. The GitHub search has a lot of limitations. I think the worst of these is that it only shows the first two matches from any file, so I just avoid it whenever possible.

Comment: Seems like this is the only way. Thanks!

Comment: Though, You can not use it to search whole group or whole github.com this way.

Comment: Is this still true? I would like to search for the string  "LIB = " but it seems both ignoring the uppercase and the character "=".

Thanks

Comment: That's fine for a single repository, or a small handful, but pretty frustrating when you're trying to search across an entire organisation.

Comment: I wrote an answer with a bunch of details on that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60843047/locating-a-function-in-a-git-repository/60843055#60843055

Comment: And if such a repository mas many GB of data (and you don't want to clone all these GB)?

Comment: If download speed is the problem, then rent a VPS. You can ssh into your VPS, clone the repository there, and then search it with `grep`, `git grep`, and `rg`. This costs money, but probably a lot less money than a faster internet connection. Also, if it saves you time then you can use that saved time to earn more money.

Comment: This doesn't help if you are searching across multiple repositories unless you have them all locally. Which is a non-starter if you are, for example, checking which repos in your org are using a particular configuration option from the internal library that you wrote....

Comment: It’s pretty trivial to [clone every repository in a github org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19576742/how-to-clone-all-repos-at-once-from-github).

Answer (score 48):

Say you want results for `my_var` but not `MY_VAR`.  Use this regex search:

```
/(?-i)my_var/
```

The `-i` flag here is essentially the opposite of the same `grep` option (grep is case-sensitive by default and `-i` makes it case-insensitive).

This is a new option included in the rollout of [GitHub's blog on new Code Search feature](https://github.blog/2023-05-08-github-code-search-is-generally-available/).

[GitHub Docs: GitHub Code Search syntax](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/github-code-search/understanding-github-code-search-syntax)

Answer (score 6):

There is an indirect way. Hit `.` (which will redirect you to github.dev) to open the repo in VSCode for the Browser.

There you can do a case-sensitive search.