# Locating a function in a git repository

Tags: git, search, grep, jupyter-notebook, find

I am new to Github and Jupyter notebook.
I want to find a specific function in a git repository, how do I do it?
I have come to know that I could use Git grep, but I don't know the command.
Also, can I use Jupyter notebook to do this or do I have to use the terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about [Jupyter Notebook](https://jupyter.org/), but use the terminal. Make sure you have already `git clone`d the repository and are inside its directory in the terminal. Then do `git grep` from the terminal.

### Search for text within files:

#### 1. With `git grep` (you *must* be inside a git repo):

Case-sensitive search. The `-n` shows the line number where the result is found too.

```
git grep -n "my regular expression search string"
```

Case insensitive search (add `-i` here):

```
git grep -ni "my case insensitive regular expression search string"
```

Find a function usage (left parenthesis below is optional)

```
git grep -n "myFunc("
```

Grep does regular expression search. Google it for details. Regular expressions are a very powerful way to do very specific string matching. As you learn the basics, practice testing and checking your regular expression (regex) searches with this tool here: https://regex101.com/.

For additional `git grep` usage and commands, see my Q&A here: [How to `git grep` through a range of commits, all commits from the current commit back to the parent commit, or through all commits in entire repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73931035/4561887).

#### 2. With regular `grep` (works anywhere, but operates about 100x slower than `git grep`):

Same as above, except add `-r` for 'r'ecursive (to search into directories). If you want to follow symbolic links too, use `-R` instead of `-r`.

Examples:

Case-sensitive search. The `-n` shows the line number where the result is found too.

```
grep -rn "my regular expression search string"
```

Case insensitive search (add `-i` here):

```
grep -rni "my case insensitive regular expression search string"
```

Find a function usage (left parenthesis below is optional)

```
grep -rn "myFunc("
```

Find a function (following symbolic links: add `-R`):

```
grep -Rn "myFunc("
```

#### 3. [RECOMMENDED] With ripgrep (`rg`) (works anywhere, and is FASTER than both `grep` AND `git grep`, which is *incredibly* impressive!)

THIS IS THE BEST AND FASTEST OPTION!

Get ripgrep here: https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep. Ex: to install on Linux Ubuntu 18.10 or later, use this installation command:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install ripgrep
```

Example Uses:

Case-sensitive search.

```
rg "my regular expression search string"
```

Case insensitive search (add `-i` here):

```
rg -i "my regular expression search string"
```

Follow symbolic links with `-L`:

```
rg -L "my regular expression search string"
```

Note that ripgrep automatically shows line numbers (`-n`) when searching in a terminal, so there is no need to add `-n`. It is on by default!

---

### Bonus: find a file by name:

Just pipe the output of `find` to be the input to `grep` with the pipe operator (`|`):

```
find | grep -ni "my_file_name"
```

Or, use `-L` with `find` to follow symbolic links:

```
find -L | grep -ni "my_file_name"
```

Notice the `-i` above is for case-insensitive filename searches. Remove it to match the case too.

### References:

1. Random experience, Googling, and talking to people over the years
2. Read the man (manual) pages:
3. `man git grep`
4. `man grep`
5. `man find`
6. https://regex101.com/

### Related:

1. [GitHub: How to do case sensitive search for the code in repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31885572/github-how-to-do-case-sensitive-search-for-the-code-in-repository)

Comment: Does `git grep -n` search all branches? Or only the current working branch?

Comment: @John, by default it only searches the working branch--whatever is on your active file system ("working tree") at the moment, and tracked by git, I believe.

Comment: Does the aforementioned command search the file which has already been deleted in a specific commit?

Comment: @John, if it's been deleted, it's no longer in your working tree (what you see in your file system via `ls` or in a file explorer GUI), so no, it won't search it.

Comment: If the deleted file still lies in the repertory(I mean specific files were deleted by some commit, you can still restore the deleted files by `git`), is it possible to search the entire repertory?

Comment: @John, to search through a commit or list of commits, you can do this: `git grep -n "some regex search string" commit1 commit2 commit3 commit4`. To search for *changes* of a word, you can do this: [`git log -S "some string"` or `git log --all -S "some string"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54567708/4561887). I don't know how to do exactly what you've asked for, though, so I posted a new question here: [How to `git grep` through a range of commits, all commits from the current commit back to the parent commit, or through all commits in entire repo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73930303/4561887)

Comment: @John, you can also try this to search for a match in your history like this: `git log -p`, then press the `/` key, type your regular expression search string, and press `Enter`. Press `n` for "next match" or `Shift` + `n` for "previous match". The `-p` in `git log` shows the changes in "patch" format for each commit.

Comment: @John, after much effort I figured it out. See my full answer here: [How to `git grep` through a range of commits, all commits from the current commit back to the parent commit, or through all commits in entire repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73931035/4561887)