# Searching in multiple Github repositories

Tags: github

I Want to search all our codebase in our Github installation for different text strings. We have app. 90 different repositories.

**Is there such a method?**

I can only find search for file names, authors etc., not search for strings inside code. My task is to find every project which uses or refers to systems, classes, methods etc. that soon are obsolete.

Alternately: **Is there a method to download/clone all repositories in one action?**

We use SourceTree as client software.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can search multiple repositories by adding the `repo:` option to your query, which you can see in action on GitHub's [advanced search](https://github.com/search/advanced) page. Each repo value takes the usual `user/repository` form. For example:

```
find_me repo:me/foo repo:you/bar repo:company/baz
```

To make a list of all your repositories if you don't have one, an easy way might be GitHub's [repositories API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/).

Once you have the list, it would also be simple to clone everything with a simple shell script. I don't believe GitHub has a built-in feature for that.

```
while read repo; do
  git clone https://github.com/$repo
done < list_of_repos.txt
```

Since it sounds like you're pulling an organization's repos, [caniszczyk](https://github.com/caniszczyk) has [a Gist](https://gist.github.com/caniszczyk/3856584) doing just that. I'll copy the core of it here, but there's some discussion with updates and help for private repos.

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/orgs/twitter/repos?per_page=200 | \
ruby -rubygems -e 'require "json"; JSON.load(STDIN.read).each { |repo| %x[git clone #{repo["ssh_url"]} ]}'
```

There's also [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19576742/how-to-clone-all-repos-at-once-from-git) asking about it, and a [full backup script](https://gist.github.com/rodw/3073987) to get issues, wikis, etc.

Comment: No, the goal is to search all repos owned by one organization, without having to enumerate the repos. Search should be simple and easy.

Comment: Agreed. When I wrote this answer, the `org:` search in [opticyclic's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40569939/802618) wasn't available yet. That's now a better solution.

Comment: Also take a look at [GitHub CLI `search repos`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_search_repos) command

Answer (score 46):

You can search directly at the top of an Organisation now. This results in the prefix `org:`.

e.g. if you wanted to search all twitter repos for the word bot you would search for `org:twitter bot`

https://github.com/search?l=&q=org%3Atwitter+bot&ref=advsearch&type=Code

Comment: Nice, works well also for issues/PRs by label, eg. `org:acme label:qa_blocker`.