# How to create GitHub repository under an organization from the command-line?

Tags: git, curl, github, command-line, github-api

It's my understanding that to create a personal repository on the command line, using the GitHub v3 API, one can do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423777/is-it-possible-to-create-a-remote-repo-on-github-from-the-cli-without-opening-br) (replacing USERNAME and REPONAME appropriately):

```
curl -u 'USERNAME' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"REPONAME"}'
```

The user then enters their username and password, and GitHub will create a new empty repository at "github.com/USERNAME/REPONAME".

My question is, how do I create an organization-owned repository via command line? I tried replacing USERNAME with the organization's name, and it prompted me for the 'host password'. I own the organization so I entered my password but I got "Bad credentials". Does this method not work for organization-owned repositories? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To create a repository under an organisation you should send the request to the `POST /orgs/:org/repos` endpoint rather than `/user/repos`. Your user shouldn't need any extra permissions or scopes over what is required to create a user repository, but the user must be a member of `:org`:

> ### Create
>
> Create a new repository for the authenticated user. **(Currently not enabled for Integrations)**
>
> `POST /user/repos`
>
> Create a new repository in this organization. The authenticated user must be a member of the specified organization.
>
> `POST /orgs/:org/repos`

(From https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create)

Comment: For clarification, do I keep the `:` in the `:org`? For example, if my organization name was 'foo' would the request be `POST /orgs/:foo/repos` or `POST /orgs/foo/repos`?

Comment: You do not keep the colon. It only designates it as a variable. You can see an example of a call made to the same endpoint here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19577228/1639983
EDIT: I know the call isn't doing the same thing, but the endpoint is still the same.

Answer (score 25):

With the new github [cli](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_create), it is as simple as:

```
gh repo create ORGNAME/REPONAME
```

Answer (score 5):

Just for completeness: Example for Git Api v3:

```
curl -u USERNAME https://api.github.com/orgs/ORGNAME/repos -d '{"name":"NAME_OF_REPO", "description":"SOME_DESCRIPTION", "private": true, "has_issues": true, "has_projects": true, "has_wiki":false }'
```

Answer (score 0):

`gh repo create ORGNAME/REPONAME` is no longer working as:
"`--public`, `--private`, or `--internal` required when not running interactively"

`gh repo create ORGNAME/REPONAME --private` -> WORKS