# Add text to start of each line after grep

Tags: bash, shell, grep, github-api

I am trying to extract name of all repositories in github and build a script file to clone all of them, using this bash script:

```
for i in {1..10}
do
curl -u USERNAME:PASS -s https://api.github.com/user/repos?page=$i | grep -oP '"clone_url": "\K(.*)"' > output$i.txt
done
```

this is my script outputs each repo name in single line, but I need to insert **git clone** to start of each line so I wrote this (added | xargs -L1 git clone), which doesn't work:

```
for i in {1..10}
do
curl -u USERNAME:PASS -s https://api.github.com/user/repos?page=$i | grep -oP '"clone_url": "\K(.*)"' | xargs -L1 git clone > output$i.txt
done
```

Comment: Note you want `grep -oP '"clone_url": "\K[^"]+'`, not `grep -oP '"clone_url": "\K(.*)"'`

Comment: What is output of your `curl` command?

Comment: complex json from github

Comment: seems like a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19576742/how-to-clone-all-repos-at-once-from-github  -- note the one-liner solution

Comment: @AVEbrahimi I have completed my answer with a fully featured example https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134024/7939871

Comment: ... or  `...| sed "s/^/git clone /"`, better than `| xargs echo`!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append string with xargs using echo

```
for i in {1..10}
do
curl -u use_name:pass -s https://api.github.com/user/repos?page=$i | grep -oP '"clone_url": "\K(.*)"' |  tr -d '"' | xargs -n 1 echo 'git clone'
done
```

Also, you can do this using Perl.

```
for i in {1..10}
do
curl -u user_name:pass -s https://api.github.com/user/repos?page=$i | grep -oP '"clone_url": "\K(.*)"' |  tr -d '"' | perl -ne 'print "git clone $_"' > output$i.txt
done
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Using `jq` is always the best option to parse JSON data:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for i in {1..10}
do
  curl \
    --user USERNAME:PASS \
    --silent \
    "https://api.github.com/user/repos?page=${i}" \
  | jq \
    --raw-output '.[] | "git clone \(.clone_url)"' \
    > "output${i}.txt"
done
```

Or to handle an arbitrary number of pages, you can tell `jq` to return a non-null return-code in `$?` by providing it with the `--exit-status` option.

Then if the JSON selector returns no result (witch happens when the returned GitHub API's result page is empty) the `jq` return-code can be tested to continue or terminate the while loop:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

typeset -i page=1 # GitHub API paging starts at page 1

while clone_cmds="$(
  curl \
    --user USERNAME:PASS \
    --silent \
    "https://api.github.com/user/repos?page=${page}" \
    | jq \
      --exit-status \
      --raw-output \
      '.[] | "git clone \(.clone_url)"'
)"; do
  # The queried page result length is > 0
  # Output to the paged file
  # and increase page number
  echo >"output$((page++)).txt" "${clone_cmds}"
done
```

If you want the same as above but all repositories in a single file.

The following example feature GitHub API handling of pages, rather than relying on an extra empty request to mark the end of the pages.

It now also handles pages of up to 100 entries, and negotiate a compressed transport stream if supported.

Here is the featured version of your repository cloning list:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Set either one to authenticate with the GitHub API.
# GitHub 'Oauth2 token':
OAUTH_TOKEN=''
# GitHub 'username:password':
USER_PASS=''

# The GitHub API Base URL:
typeset -r GITHUB_API='https://api.github.com'

# The array of Curl options to authenticate with GitHub:
typeset -a curl_auth

# Populates the authentication options from what is available.
if [[ -n ${OAUTH_TOKEN} ]]; then
  curl_auth=(--header "Authorization: token ${OAUTH_TOKEN}")
elif [[ -n ${USER_PASS} ]]; then
  curl_auth=(--user "${USER_PASS}")
else
  # These $"string" are bash --dump-po-strings ready.
  printf >&2 $"GitHub API need an authentication with either set variable:"$'\n'
  printf >&2 "OAUTH_TOKEN='%s'\\n" $"GitHub API's Oauth2 token"
  printf >&2 $"or"" USER_PASS='%s:%s'.\\n" $"username" $"password"
  printf >&2 $"See: %s"$'\n' 'https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication'
  exit 1
fi

# Query the GitHub API for user repositories.
# The default results count per page is 30.
# It can be raised up to 100, to limit the number
# of requests needed to retrieve all the results.
# Response headers contains a Link: <url>; rel="next" as
# long as there is a next page.
# See: https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination

# Compose the API URL for the first page.
next_page_url="${GITHUB_API}/user/repos?per_page=100&page=1"

# While there is a next page URL to query...
while [[ -n ${next_page_url} ]]; do

  # Send the API request with curl, and get back a complete
  # http_response witch --include response headers, and
  # if supported, handle a --compressed data stream,
  # keeping stderr &2 --silent.
  http_response="$(
    curl \
      --silent \
      --include \
      --compressed \
      "${curl_auth[@]}" \
      "${next_page_url}"
  )"

  # Get the next page URL from the Link: header.
  # Reaching the last page, causes the next_page_url
  # variable to be empty.
  next_page_url="$(
    sed \
      --silent \
      '/^[[:space:]]*$/,$d;s/Link:.*<\(.*\)>;[[:space:]]*rel="next".*$/\1/p' \
      <<<"${http_response}"
  )"

  # Get the http_body part from the http_response.
  http_body="$(sed '1,/^[[:space:]]*$/d' <<<"${http_response}")"

  # Query the http_body JSON content with jq.
  jq --raw-output '.[] | "git clone \(.clone_url)"' <<<"${http_body}"

done >"output.txt" # Redirect the whole while loop output to the file.
```

Answer (score 1):

`grep` can't substitute strings, but `sed` can easily replace `grep` and also perform substitutions:

```sh
for i in {1..10}
do
    curl -u USERNAME:PASS -s "https://api.github.com/user/repos?page=$i" |
    sed -n 's/.*"clone_url": "\([^"]*\)".*/git clone "\1"/p' > "output$i.txt"
done
```

Notice also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) and the use of `[^"]` in the regex to specifically say that the extracted text mustn't contain a double quote.

As such, I agree with, and have upvoted, the answer which suggests to use `jq` instead whenever your input is JSON.

Comment: just for my learning, please can explain what is wrong in my answer, Thanks

Comment: If you are asking for my opinion, the main objection I would raise is that you pile on processes organically at the end instead of thinking it through. Perl can do everything `grep` and `tr` can do, and then some. The `tr -d '"'` looks like a weird compromise; removing random characters in the middle of an extracted URL is just going to break it, and if you extracted more than just the URL, merely deleting a double quote is absolutely not going to fix it.

Comment: Many  Thanks, Got your point and will try to improve my bash skills, its mean that just the output is not important one should keep in mind the above thing, Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0):

Your second script works, you just need to clean up the grep search pattern so it does not include an unmatched trailing quote:

```
 grep  -oP '"clone_url": \K(.*)\"' | xargs -L1 echo git clone
```