# How to download GitHub Release from private repo using command line

Tags: shell, github, command-line

[GitHub guide](https://help.github.com/articles/downloading-files-from-the-command-line) explains 2 way to authorize but looks neither of those works with the Release files.

as a result of:

```sh
curl -u 'username' -L -o a.tgz https://github.com/company/repository/releases/download/TAG-NAME/A.tgz
```

There always is something like

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
Hello future GitHubber! ...
```

Comment: The best answer I have found so far is this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/25923939/772000

Comment: `gh release download ...` - https://cli.github.com

Answer (score 93):

To download release file from private repo, you can use Personal access token which can be generated at [settings/tokens](https://github.com/settings/tokens) with *Full control of private repositories* scope.

Then download the asset with `curl` command (change with appropriate values):

```
curl -vLJO -H 'Authorization: token my_access_token' 'https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/releases/assets/:id'
```

or if you're using an OAuth app, use:

```
curl -u my_client_id:my_client_secret https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/releases/assets/:id
```

where:

- `:owner` is your user or organisation username;
- `:repo` is your repository name;
- `:id` is your asset id, can be found in tag release URL, like:

  ```
  https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/releases/tags/:tag
  ```
- `:token` is your personal access token (can be created at `/settings/tokens`;

Note: Using `access_token` as a query param is [deprecated](https://developer.github.com/changes/2020-02-10-deprecating-auth-through-query-param/#changes-to-make).

See: [Repositories API v3 at GitHub](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/)

---

Here is the Bash script which can download asset file given specific name of file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Script to download asset file from tag release using GitHub API v3.
# See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35688093/55075    
CWD="$(cd -P -- "$(dirname -- "$0")" && pwd -P)"

# Check dependencies.
set -e
type curl grep sed tr >&2
xargs=$(which gxargs || which xargs)

# Validate settings.
[ -f ~/.secrets ] && source ~/.secrets
[ "$GITHUB_API_TOKEN" ] || { echo "Error: Please define GITHUB_API_TOKEN variable." >&2; exit 1; }
[ $# -ne 4 ] && { echo "Usage: $0 [owner] [repo] [tag] [name]"; exit 1; }
[ "$TRACE" ] && set -x
read owner repo tag name <<<$@

# Define variables.
GH_API="https://api.github.com"
GH_REPO="$GH_API/repos/$owner/$repo"
GH_TAGS="$GH_REPO/releases/tags/$tag"
AUTH="Authorization: token $GITHUB_API_TOKEN"
WGET_ARGS="--content-disposition --auth-no-challenge --no-cookie"
CURL_ARGS="-LJO#"

# Validate token.
curl -o /dev/null -sH "$AUTH" $GH_REPO || { echo "Error: Invalid repo, token or network issue!";  exit 1; }

# Read asset tags.
response=$(curl -sH "$AUTH" $GH_TAGS)
# Get ID of the asset based on given name.
eval $(echo "$response" | grep -C3 "name.:.\+$name" | grep -w id | tr : = | tr -cd '[[:alnum:]]=')
#id=$(echo "$response" | jq --arg name "$name" '.assets[] | select(.name == $name).id') # If jq is installed, this can be used instead. 
[ "$id" ] || { echo "Error: Failed to get asset id, response: $response" | awk 'length($0)<100' >&2; exit 1; }
GH_ASSET="$GH_REPO/releases/assets/$id"

# Download asset file.
echo "Downloading asset..." >&2
curl $CURL_ARGS -H "Authorization: token $GITHUB_API_TOKEN" -H 'Accept: application/octet-stream' "$GH_ASSET"
echo "$0 done." >&2
```

Before running, you need to set your `GITHUB_API_TOKEN` with your GitHub token (see: `/settings/tokens` at GH). This can be placed in your `~/.secrets` file, like:

```
GITHUB_API_TOKEN=XXX
```

Example script usage:

```
./get_gh_asset.sh :owner :repo :tag :name
```

where name is your filename (or partial of it). Prefix script with `TRACE=1` to debug it.

---

In case you wonder why `curl` fails sometimes with (as mentioned in other answer):

> Only one auth mechanism allowed; only the `X-Amz-Algorithm` query parameter, Signature query string parameter or the `Authorization` header should be specified.

when running like:

```
curl -vLJ -H 'Authorization: token <token>' -H 'Accept: application/octet-stream' https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/releases/assets/<id>
```

this is because you're specifying multiple mechanism at the same time, so S3 server doesn't know which one to use, therefore you have to choose only one, such as:

- `X-Amz-Algorithm` query parameter
- Signature query string parameter (`X-Amz-Signature`)
- Authorization header (`Authorization: token <token>`)

and since GitHub redirects you from asset page (when requesting `application/octet-stream`), it populates credentials automatically in query string and since `curl` is passing over the same credentials in the request header (which you've specified), therefore they're conflicting. So as for workaround you can use `access_token` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the script @kenorb, I will use it to allow my ansible playbook to grab release .deb files from a private repo. Much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the script. If the `jq` JSON utility is installed, extracting the asset id can be greatly simplified with `ASSET_ID=$(echo "$response" | jq --arg name "$name" '.assets[] | select(.name == $name).id')` or the likes.

Comment: NOTE: using access_token as query param is deprecated: https://developer.github.com/changes/2020-02-10-deprecating-auth-through-query-param/#changes-to-make

Comment: @joonas.fi Thanks for the suggestion, I've updated my answer.

Comment: `Full control of private repositories scope` for getting just the release data? Is there any other scope I can use, coz I just don't want to authorize everything but `only releases`

Comment: agree with @EctoRuseff, it is scary the access level to do this :o

Comment: Great script, many thanks!
Maybe `awk` should also be added to the dependency check?

BTW: Do you have it published on some public code repository?

Comment: @EctoRuseff Thankfully there is a new BETA on GitHub that's called Fine-grained tokens which solves exactly this issue (selective repos, selective permissions (read-only, write, ...)

Comment: How do I get asset_id?

Comment: The personal access token used must have scope repo and project:read access.

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to change `Authorization: token <token>` to `Authorization: Bearer <token>`

Answer (score 27):

We had to download release assets from private GitHub repos fairly often, so we created [fetch](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/fetch), which is an open source, cross-platform tool that makes it easy to download source files and release assets from a git tag, commit, or branch of public and private GitHub repos.

For example, to download the release asset `foo.exe` from version `0.1.3` of a private GitHub repo to `/tmp`, you would do the following:

```
GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN="your token"
fetch --repo="https://github.com/foo/bar" --tag="0.1.3" --release-asset="foo.exe" /tmp
```

Comment: Just adding a comment here that fetch is a standalone executable, and does exactly what the original poster is requesting. I've incorporated it into my team's build process as well.

Comment: ONLY answer that actually worked for me.  Tried to get one specific asset from a github release at a private repo, and only this one did the trick.

Comment: I had to actually specify the `--github-oauth-token=${GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN}` flag. Works fantastically then.

Answer (score 10):

Seems both authentication methods only work for the API endpoints.
There's an API endpoint for downloading release assets ([docu](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#get-a-single-release-asset)):

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/releases/assets/:id
```

But one will need to know the asset's numerical ID for that.
I asked their support whether they could add an API endpoint to download release assets by name (like they have for tarballs).

---

Update: Response from Github support:

> We don't offer any API like you're suggesting.  We try to avoid brittle URLs that would change if the tag or filename of the release asset change.  I'll take your feedback to the team to discuss further.

Comment: I'm looking for a easy way to get the latest asset. As long as I've understood I need to get the list of releases, pick the id of the latest, get the release with the asset ids and download finally the asset. Is there a way to download the asset by the tag name?

Comment: There's sort of an example of the technique here: http://brantiffy.axisj.com/archives/215, https://github.com/brant-hwang/get-git-private-repo-latest-release-zip. You can probably tweak the code to use tag name instead of ID, etc.

Answer (score 10):

Use [gh release download](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_release_download) to easily script downloads. [gh auth login](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login) first to authorise.

So to download the examples URL `https://github.com/company/repository/releases/download/TAG-NAME/A.tgz` use:

`gh release download --repo company/repository TAG-NAME -p 'A.tgz'`

Answer (score 6):

I found out the answer in this comment: https://github.com/request/request/pull/1058#issuecomment-55285276

`curl` is forwarding the authentication header in the request to the AmazonS3 bucket, where the Github release assets are stored.
Error response from S3:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
 <Code>InvalidArgument</Code>
 <Message>
   Only one auth mechanism allowed; only the X-Amz-Algorithm query parameter, Signature query string parameter or the Authorization header should be specified
 </Message>
 <ArgumentName>Authorization</ArgumentName>
 <ArgumentValue>token <yourtoken> </ArgumentValue><RequestId>4BEDDBA630688865</RequestId> <HostId>SXLsRKgKM6tPa/K7g7tSOWmQEqowG/4kf6cwOmnpObXrSzUt4bzOFuihmzxK6+gx</HostId>
</Error>
```

**One line wget solution:**

```
wget --auth-no-challenge --header='Accept:application/octet-stream' https://<token>:@api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/releases/assets/:id -O app.zip
```

Try:`curl -i -H "Authorization: token <token>" -H "Accept:application/octet-stream" https://<token>:@api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/releases/assets/:id`, for some more details. Add `-L` to see the S3 error message.

Comment: Can you explain how you would generate the `<token>` in your solutions? Sorry if it's a dumb question.

Comment: Think I've answered my own question. Github API authentication is documented here: https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication

Comment: if you use curl, the workaround is to put the authentication elsewhere than as a header. Like as query string parameter method (per the API docs, "URL?access_token=TOKEN") . Can you also do "http://TOKEN:@api.github.com/..." with curl?

Answer (score 6):

Here is `curl` & [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) one;)liner:

```
CURL="curl -H 'Authorization: token <auth_token>' \
      https://api.github.com/repos/<owner>/<repo>/releases"; \
ASSET_ID=$(eval "$CURL/tags/<tag>" | jq '.assets[] | select(.name == "<name>").id'); \
eval "$CURL/assets/$ASSET_ID -LJOH 'Accept: application/octet-stream'"
```

Change parts surrounded with `<>` with your data.
To generate `auth_token` go to [github.com/settings/tokens](https://github.com/settings/tokens)

###### EDIT 2023.09.24:

login with a password is [no longer supported](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/authenticating-to-the-rest-api?apiVersion=2022-11-28#authenticating-with-username-and-password)

If you like to login with a password use this (note it will ask for a password twice):

```
CURL="curl -u <github_user> https://api.github.com/repos/<owner>/<repo>/releases"; \
ASSET_ID=$(eval "$CURL/tags/<tag>" | jq '.assets[0].id'); \
eval "$CURL/assets/$ASSET_ID -LJOH 'Accept: application/octet-stream'"
```

Comment: You can replace `tags/<tag>` with `latest` to get the latest release.

Comment: The latest release seems to need just `/latest` now, i.e. `"$CURL/latest"`

Comment: The new Github token system seems to require the -u method, i.e. `-u username:token`

Comment: You assume that your target will always be the first item in the `.assets` array. That may not be the case. That's why others use `jq` with `select()` to search for the correct `.name`.

Comment: Thanks @Cliff! Edited my answer to allow specifying an asset by name + removed auth via pwd as not supported.

Answer (score 4):

An easier working solution is to use .netrc to store credentials. This way, curl does not forward credentials to Amazon S3 Bucket

In `~/.netrc` file (should be created with 0600 file permission):

```
machine api.github.com
login yourusername
password yourpassword
```

Then use the curl -n option to use .netrc:

```
curl -L -O -J -n -H "Accept:application/octet-stream" https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/releases/assets/:id
```

Comment: Too bad this option is a bit more hassle when you run on dynamic hosts/configs that don't have the .netrc file by default, like newly spawned VMs/environments for which you can't define a pre-configured image. Like CircleCI for example, I think.

Comment: @David Well, you can also write the 3 lines to the .netrc file programatically in the head of your script, it remains the easiest solution.

Comment: It also works on windows, but the netrc file may be named ~/_netrc instead of ~/.netrc

Comment: As a word of warning: it is not recommended to put the token into a `.netrc` file on a server. A potential hacker can leverage this to get full access to all the user's private repositories on GitHub.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a "one-liner" using `wget` for making HTTP requests and `python` for JSON parsing:

```
(export AUTH_TOKEN=<oauth-token>; \
 export ASSET_ID=$(wget -O - https://api.github.com/repos/<owner>/<repo>/releases/tags/<tag>?access_token=$AUTH_TOKEN | python -c 'import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)["assets"][0]["id"]'); \
 wget --header='Accept:application/octet-stream' -O <download-name> https://api.github.com/repos/<owner>/<repo>/releases/assets/$ASSET_ID?access_token=$AUTH_TOKEN)
```

To use it, just replace `<oauth-token>`, `<owner>`, `<repo>`, `<tag>` and  `<download-name>` with appropriate values.

Explanation:

- The first statement (`export AUTH_TOKEN=<oauth-token>`) sets [GitHub OAuth token](https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication) which is used by the subsequent `wget` commands.
- The second statement has two parts:

  1. The `wget -O - https://api.github.com/repos/<owner>/<repo>/releases/tags/<tag>?access_token=$AUTH_TOKEN` part [gets GitHub release information from a tag name](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#get-a-release-by-tag-name) and prints it on *stdout*.
  2. The `python -c 'import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)["assets"][0]["id"]'` part parses JSON from *stdin* and extracts the `id` of the (first) release asset.
- The third statement (`wget --header='Accept:application/octet-stream' -O <tarball-name>.tar.gz https://api.github.com/repos/<owner>/<repo>/releases/assets/$ASSET_ID?access_token=$AUTH_TOKEN)`) [gets a single GitHub release asset by id](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#get-a-single-release-asset) and stores it to a file.
- The outer parentheses create a subshell and ensure exported environment variables are discarded afterwards.

Comment: https://developer.github.com/changes/2020-02-10-deprecating-auth-through-query-param

Answer (score 3):

Like @dwayne I solved this using the gh CLI which you would also need to to install. As I was inside a docker container I needed to install `curl`, `dirmngr`, then the `gh` CLI and then download the release like below. Also shows how to authenticate using a personal token to the gh cli, and unzip the release files (a tarball in my case).

```
FROM debian:10.9 as base
RUN apt update \
 # Install package dependencies
 && apt install -y \
    build-essential \
    wget \
    dirmngr \
    curl

# Install GH CLI - see https://github.com/cli/cli/blob/trunk/docs/install_linux.md
RUN curl -fsSL https://cli.github.com/packages/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg | gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg && \
   echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg] https://cli.github.com/packages stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/github-cli.list > /dev/null && \
   apt update && \
   apt install -y gh

# auth to github with PAT and download release
ARG RELEASE_TOKEN
RUN echo $RELEASE_TOKEN | gh auth login --with-token && \
   cd /opt && \
   gh release download YOUR_TAG_HERE --repo https://github.com/SOME_ORG/SOME-REPO && \
   tar -xjf SOME-RELEASE-FILES.tar.bz2 -C /opt && \
   rm SOME-RELEASE-FILES.tar.bz2
```

Answer (score 0):

One-line way to do this using only curl, where:

```
# YOUR_TOKEN = your access token e.g. ghp_xxxxxxxxxxxxx
# YOUR_GITHUBCOM_URL = the portion of the URL that comes after https://github.com/ e.g. myuser/myrepo/assets/127345322/d0ad7915-a6a3-4aef-adf7-369c95e13316
# YOUR_DESTINATION = the location on your local drive to save the result to e.g. /tmp/x.png

curl "$(TOKEN=YOUR_TOKEN GITHUBCOM_URL=YOUR_GITHUBCOM_URL && curl -i -H "Authorization: token $TOKEN" https://github.com/$GITHUBCOM_URL | grep '^location: ' | sed 's/location: //' | tr -d '\r' )" > YOUR_DESTINATION
```

Tested on MacOS

Explanation:

1. Inner `curl`, using your token, fetches the metadata from github.com, which includes a signed URL that contains the actual content to fetch
2. Metadata is parsed to retrieve the line that starts with `location:`
3. `location:`  prefix and ending `\r` suffix are removed, so we are left only with the URL
4. Outer `curl` retrieves the resource using the