# How do I download binary files of a GitHub release?

Tags: git, github, binary, tags, release

I have a repo with binary files in it that I need.

I can

```
git checkout tags/thetagoftherelease
```

which seems to checkout the correct tag, but does not pull down the binary files. How can I pull down the binary files that were added to the release (the green boxes on the release)?

Added picture of binary files in a release.

[image]

Comment: Down votes with no comments are not helpful

Comment: *Pull* or *checkout*? Those are two very distinct terms in Git. Also, what "green boxes"?

Comment: Sorry, was using pull colloquially. Green boxes as in, added binary files to a release on git. They show up as green boxes that you can manually download on github. I want to download these added binary files from the release. Checking out the release tag does not give me the binary files.

Comment: As I understand it, those releases are a GitHub feature and are not part of your repo. I don't think you can download them from GitHub using Git commands.

Comment: Thanks @Jubobs , I'll accept that as the answer if you post it.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I've tried for days trying to find the proper answer to this, and finally I figured out how to do this via the curl command. It's a 3-step process.

First, to get a list of the assets for the latest release:

```
curl -H "Authorization: token YOURGITHUBTOKEN" \
    https://api.github.com/repos/NAME/REPO/releases/latest
```

Then in the JSON, look up the url of the asset you want. For example it would look like:

```
"url": "https://api.github.com/repos/NAME/REPO/releases/assets/1275759"
```

Then you pass this to another curl command to retrieve the actual URL, which is actually a link to an Amazon S3 file.

```
curl -H "Authorization: token YOURGITHUBTOKEN" \
     -H "Accept:application/octet-stream" \
     -i https://api.github.com/repos/NAME/REPO/releases/assets/1275759
```

The URL will be in the "location" field of the HTTP response, and then use curl to get the file like this:

```
curl "https://github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com...." -i -o FILENAME
```

Comment: best answer, thanks.Forget curl, use the http://httpie.org (CLI HTTP client, user-friendly curl replacement with intuitive UI, JSON support, syntax highlighting, wget-like downloads, extensions, etc.)

Comment: Make sure to use quotes to surround the s3 url. Otherwise curl won't get it apropiately.

Comment: What "location field in the HTTP response? Doesn't work for me

Answer (score 9):

Binary release assets exist outside of Git, and cannot be managed using the standard tools.

They should be available via GitHub's API, though.

1. [List the repository's release assets](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#list-assets-for-a-release):

   ```
   GET /repos/:owner/:repo/releases/:id/assets
   ```

   This will send back a JSON document listing the release assets for the repository, e.g.

   ```json
   [
     {
       "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/releases/assets/1",
       "browser_download_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World/releases/download/v1.0.0/example.zip",
       "id": 1,
       "name": "example.zip",
       "label": "short description",
       "state": "uploaded",
       "content_type": "application/zip",
       "size": 1024,
       "download_count": 42,
       "created_at": "2013-02-27T19:35:32Z",
       "updated_at": "2013-02-27T19:35:32Z",
       "uploader": {
         "login": "octocat",
         ...
       }
     }
   ]
   ```
2. [Retrieve the assts from the release you want](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#get-a-single-release-asset), as defined by its `id` from above:

   ```
   GET /repos/:owner/:repo/releases/assets/:id
   ```

   > If you want to download the asset's binary content, pass a media type of `"application/octet-stream"`. The API will either redirect the client to the location, or stream it directly if possible. API clients should handle both a `200` or `302` response.

As [documented](https://developer.github.com/v3/#root-endpoint), these requests are all relative to `https://api.github.com`.

Answer (score 4):

### One-Step Process:

Here's a one-liner (*sans auth*) I used in a script to download *Digital Ocean*'s `doctl` interface from Github. It just grabs the **LATEST** release and unTARs it:

```
curl -sL $(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/digitalocean/doctl/releases/latest | grep "http.*linux-amd64.tar.gz" | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's|[\"\,]*||g') | tar xzvf -
```

If not using Linux, replace `"http.*linux-amd64.tar.gz"` in the above with "darwin", "windows", etc and the appropriate arch.

**NOTE**: The above *should* work programmatically grabbing binaries from other Github repos, but I've only tested it with `doctl`.  HTH-

Answer (score 3):

This is a mini script to download an asset knowing its file name (can be easily modified to download other assets:

```sh
asseturl=$(curl -H "Authorization: token ${token}" https://api.github.com/repos/${repo}/releases/${releaseid}/assets | jq ".[] | select(.name==\"${filename}\") | .url")
curl -L -H "Authorization: token ${token}" -H "Accept:application/octet-stream" $(echo $asseturl | tr -d '"') > ${filename}
```

- `$token` is the access token for github
- `$filename` is the filename for the asset
- `$releaseid` is the releaseid where the binary file is stored

Comment: if you dont know the `releaseid` you can filter `/repos/{owner}/{repo}/releases` by name with `curl -H "Authorization: token ${token}" https://api.github.com/repos/${owner}/${repo}/releases | jq -r ".[] | select(.name == \"${releasename}\") | .assets[] | select(.name == \"${filename}\") | .url"`

Answer (score 2):

For Ansible, you can use this tasklist (same steps as @ted):

```
- name: Get latest version
  uri:
    url: "https://api.github.com/repos/{{github_user}}/{{github_repo}}/releases/latest"
    return_content: yes
    headers:
      Authorization: "token {{ vault_github_deploying_token }}"
  register: github_response

- set_fact:
    binary_asset_url: "{{  github_response.json.assets|json_query(query) }}"
  vars:
    query: "[?name=='{{your_github_binary_filename}}'].url | [0]"   

- name: Get Binary asset's location
  uri:
    url: "{{ binary_asset_url }}"
    return_content: no
    follow_redirects: none
    status_code: 302
    headers:
      Authorization: "token {{ vault_github_deploying_token }}"
      Accept: "application/octet-stream"
  register: assets

- name: Download binary
  get_url:
    url: "{{ assets.location }}"
    dest: "/tmp/{{ your_github_binary_filename }}"
    mode: 0755
```

Comment: Excellent! For most releases, `your_github_binary_filename` is usually `"{{ github_repo }}.tar.gz"`

Answer (score 2):

Note that `wget` cat get it directly by following download link as a browser do.

Rewrite `$URL` as you need. My convention is to upload with a suffix for binary version.

A sample script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# You can fetch some binary directly from release on github
#
# We encourage to build your own version from source.
#

GIT_USER=me
GIT_PROJECT=project_name
BASE_URL=https://github.com/$GIT_USER/$GIT_PROJECT/releases/download
RELEASE=v0.6.3-alpha1
BINARY=bin_file_on_release

if [[ -e $BINARY ]]
then
  echo "file in the way: '$BINARY' remove it."
  exit 1
fi

if [[ $(getconf LONG_BIT) == "64" ]]
then
    echo "I'm 64-bits"
    URL="$BASE_URL/$RELEASE/$BINARY"
else
    echo "I'm 32-bits"
    URL="$BASE_URL/$RELEASE/${BINARY}-32bits"
fi

set -e
echo "Fetching from: $URL"
wget -q -O $BINARY "$URL"
file $BINARY
chmod a+x $BINARY
```