# NPM install/dependency from a GitHub Release Binary

Tags: github, npm, npm-install

I know how to make an NPM dependency from a GitHub release :

```json
"dependencies": {
  "package-name": "user/repo#v1.0.0"
}
```

That's nice, but I want to install a **specific binary** from this release.

I tried

```json
"dependencies": {
  "package-name": "https://github.com/user/repo/releases/download/v1.0.0/bin.tgz"
}
```

But I gives me the following error :

```bash
❯ npm install
npm ERR! fetch failed https://github.com/user/repo/releases/download/v1.0.0/bin.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with status code 404
```

Binary release assets [exist outside of GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25923939/how-do-i-download-binary-files-of-a-github-release) and are using AWS S3.

The URL `github.com/user/repo/releases/download/v1.0.0/bin.tgz` is redirecting with a `302` status and a HTTP location header set to `https://github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com/releases/XXX/XXX...`

If I try directly with the S3 URL I got a ENAMETOOLONG error ([see NPM issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10516)) :

```bash
> npm install https://github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com/releases/XXX/XXX...
npm ERR! tarball.destroy is not a function
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: ENAMETOOLONG: name too long, open '/var/folders/pn/......
```

Questions :

- Why is NPM not following the redirect?
- Why a `404`?
- Is there a way to link an NPM dependency to a GitHub release's binary tarball? How?

---

My context and needs :

- I have a private GitHub repository
- My package needs to be built before "deploying" ([transpilation](https://babeljs.io/), etc.)
- I want to "publish" a tarball of this build in my GitHub release and directly reference it to my NPM dependencies
- I use a CI service to build, make the tarball and upload it next to the GitHub release
- I would like to use GitHub release binary as a NPM repository

Related

- SO question: [How to install an npm package from GitHub directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509669/how-to-install-nodejs-package-from-github-directly/17509764)
- NPM issue: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3055

Answer (score 2):

I don't think npm provides a way to do this as per their documentation, they support using github's tarballs but not a specific binary attached to a release.
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install
The only way I see it would work is downloading the file and using the "tarball file" way described in the "npm install" docs.

I'm in the same boat and I think I'll end up using npm private repositories.

Answer (score 0):

The 404 is because you are a private repo and didn't include the authentication in the url.

Public repo:

```
"agentframework": "https://codeload.github.com/agentframework/agentframework/tar.gz/beta"
```

Private repo:

1. Create a private access token https://github.com/settings/tokens
2. Create your own http proxy to download the assert from release. https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#get-a-single-release-asset
3. Add the http proxy url to your package.json

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "agentframework": "https://codeload.github.com/agentframework/agentframework/tar.gz/beta"
  }
}
```

BTW: You can use `yarn install` which I used in my projects

Comment: Can you explain in more detail how you set up the http proxy?

Comment: Same 404 happens with public repos

Comment: @FLekschas, Thank you for pointing out this issue. I just check the code and found the reason is because GitHub changed their domain for downloading the releases. I have updated the answer. please try the new domain codeload.github.com

Answer (score -1):

Github Releases are based on Git Tags.

> "...Versions are based on Git
>   tags."

https://help.github.com/articles/creating-releases/

To specify a version with a Git URL, include an appropriate , such as a tag, at the end as a URL fragment.
Example, for a tag named 0.3.1:

```
"dependencies": {
  "myprivatemodule": "git@github.com:...#0.3.1"
}
```

The snipped portion (...) should be filled in:

```
"myprivatemodule": "git@github.com:{owner}/{project}.git#0.3.1"
```

And, a different address format will be needed when SSH access isn't available:

```
"myprivatemodule": "git://github.com/{owner}/{project}.git#0.3.1"
```

kindly taken from: [npm install from Git in a specific version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187956/npm-install-from-git-in-a-specific-version)

Comment: This works fine to have npm install from the codebase itself, but not to use binaries (e.g. a tarball containing build artifacts) uploaded to github releases