# How to install an already distributable Python package (wheel) from a private github repository?

Tags: python, git, github, pip, python-packaging

I am storing distributable wheel packages from several modules in a private GitHub repository.
Here is the repository structure:

```
myrepo\
       | module1\
       |         | pyproject.toml
       |         | src\
       |         |     | *.py
       |         | dist\
       |                | module1.whl
       | module2\
                 | pyproject.toml
                 | src\
                 |     | *.py
                 | dist\
                        | module2.whl
```

Currently, I'm installing them using the `pip` tool from the source, which  works. But, each time it clones the whole repository and builds the package locally.

`pip install ssh+git://git@github.com/myorg/myrepo.git#subdirectory=module1`

Is there a way to tell pip to only download and install the `module1.whl` and `module2.whl` files and not the whole repository?

I've tried the below approaches so far, but none of them works:

```bash
pip install ssh+git://git@github.com/myorg/myrepo.git#subdirectory=module1/dist/module1-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

and

```bash
pip install https://github.com/myorg/myrepo/blob/main/module1/dist/module1-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

I've already checked existing questions like [Is it possible to use pip to install a package from a private github repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830856/is-it-possible-to-use-pip-to-install-a-package-from-a-private-github-repository) and [Distributing my python module inside organization](/questions/34210931/distributing-my-python-module-inside-organization), but none of them describe this use case.

---

**Edited**

This is already possible for Public repositories like, so it is not something strange:

```
pip install https://github.com/numpy/numpy/releases/download/vx.y.z/numpy-x.y.z.tar.gz
```

Comment: I usually use `python -m pip install -e .` when inside a similar `module1 ` for example

Edit: From within the repo you can try `python -m pip install -e module1`

Comment: I am already doing that for local development, but it is not useful for distributing across the whole organization or using in the CI/CD build systems.

Comment: You can download the wheel and then run pip install on the .whl file itself: `pip install path/to/module.whl` See https://wheel.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide.html#installing-wheels

Comment: Combine that with an operation that downloads the wheel files and you're set.

Comment: Distribute *source code* from the Git repository. Distribute wheels from a private PyPi repository.

Comment: I was going to suggest making the wheels assets in your releases, but uploading the wheels to a private PyPI repo seems even better. Downloading assets from a github release is very simple to automate.

Comment: @joanis I would love to know how that is possible for a **private** repository. I've already used it for **public** repositories.

Comment: You need to use your PAT on the curl command, and then it should work. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35280061/3216427

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After elaborate exploration, I found that it is **not** possible to install release packages of a private GitHub repository by `pip`.

The reason is that GitHub only allows downloading such files using GitHub tokens and not by deploy keys.

Suggested ways to download the file and add it to the container, or to use API tokens to download the package and install it in the container and install it from there are not viable as well. Because you either have to update the file manually, or update the API token.

The only possible way is to create a private package repository on google and push the release packages there.