# How to download GitHub release asset from private repo using only java

Tags: java, git, github, github-api

I've seen [How to download GitHub Release from private repo using command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20396329/how-to-download-github-release-from-private-repo-using-command-line) on how to download a github release asset from command line but I was wondering if anybody has figured how to do it in 100% java? I can find the id of the asset and the have the owner and repository name using https://github.com/kohsuke/github-api.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Following snippet shows the principle.

```
String credentials = "github.credentials";
GitHub gitHub = GitHubBuilder.fromPropertyFile(credentials)
        .withRateLimitHandler(RateLimitHandler.FAIL)
        .build();
GHRepository repository = gitHub.getRepository("suboptimal/examples-repo");
for (GHRelease release : repository.listReleases()) {
    System.out.println("release: " + release.getName());
    System.out.println("assets :");
    for (GHAsset asset : release.getAssets()) {
        System.out.printf("   %s - %s%n", asset.getName(),
            asset.getBrowserDownloadUrl());
    }
}
```

assuming the file `github.credentials` contains

```
login=your_user_name
password=your_access_token
```

The access token can be created for your GitHub user at https://github.com/settings/tokens.

output

```
release: v0.1
assets :
  asset-demo.txt - https://github.com/SubOptimal/examples-repo/releases/download/v0.1/asset-demo.txt
```

You can verify it at 
https://api.github.com/repos/SubOptimal/examples-repo/releases/assets/28055588

(for a private repo you would need to be logged in into GitHub).