# Download a file using cURL that has been uploaded to a GHE release

Tags: github, github-enterprise

I'm using **GitHub Enterprise** and I uploaded a large binary file to the Release section of a repo.  The link to the download file is https://git.mycompany.com/theuser/therepo/releases/download/0.0.1-alpha/large.file.

What's the proper way to download this file using cURL?

Every time I try to cURL the file, I get a response saying that I'm being redirected, or I get garbage back.  I'm able to cURL a file that's inside the actual repo using the raw link to the file (which has a token in the URL).

I've tried various combinations of cURL against the GitHub API, and other URLs, but nothing is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Every time I try to cURL the file, I get a response saying that I'm being redirected

Make sure to use `curl -L` to follow redirections.

> or I get garbage back

Make sure to use `curl -O afile` or otherwise the result of the download would be directly on stdout.

So in short

```
curl -L -O afile https://git.mycompany.com/theuser/therepo/releases/download/0.0.1-alpha/large.file
```

Or use the ["Latest release asset" GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#get-a-single-release-asset), combined with [this `curl` tutorial](https://gist.github.com/caspyin/2288960).

```
curl -vLJO -H 'Accept: application/octet-stream' 'https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/releases/assets/:id?access_token=:token'
```

See more at "[How to download GitHub Release from private repo using command line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35688093/6309)".

If your repo is not a private one, you might not need a token access.