# GitHub personal access tokens scope only for getting releases data from private repo

Tags: github, github-api

To get personal access tokens: https://github.com/settings/tokens

I have a private repository, from which I want to get the releases data *(https://github.com/**user_name**/**repo_name**/releases)*. What scopes should I use for that purpose?

**Important note:** I just want auth to the releases data only, not to the whole private repo.

**What I've tried:** [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35688093/14387519) suggests to use `Full control of private repositories scope`, but I don't want to authorize the whole repository access, just the releases data.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding [API calls](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/getting-started-with-the-rest-api#repositories), the documentation still mention:

> A token with [`repo` scope](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps#available-scopes) returns a response that includes all public and private repositories we have access to see on github.com.

And that scope does grant full access to private and public repositories.

Try with a token screated with `repo:status`, for testing: that would not grant write access.

Comment: `repo:status` working fine for public repositories, but **not for private** repositories

Comment: @EctoRuseff Then, in term of '`scope`', there is only `repo`, which does grant write access to private repos...