# How to download NPM package published to GitHub packages registry as a zip?

Tags: node.js, github, github-api

I am using GitHub packages to publish my private NPM packages. I need to download the published package of specific version for carrying out automation work. How can I download the package as a zip bundle using GitHub REST API or equivalent? Additionally, since it is a private package, it needs to be authenticated.

I know that [equivalent functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20396329/5723098) exists but it works for GitHub releases and assets. I could not find anything yet for GitHub packages!

Comment: When you say a zip bundle, are you specifically trying to retrieve the package contents as a compressed zipped folder with a `.zip` file extension? 
Because I was under the impression the only accessible assets from an npm package published via GitHub packages, private or otherwise, would be a `.tgz`.

Comment: `zip` or `.tgz` - anything is fine as long as I can download it.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment there is only one option for obtaining the archive. Use the following link "https://npm.pkg.github.com/@org-name%2fpackage-name" and view the metadata. Many thanks to @Nathan Williams.

Comment: can you please provide an actual example? What does the metadata look like? And how do I go from there to actually downloading the file?

Answer (score 0):

After a few days of intermittent research regarding this question, here is what I have found. There seem to be two methods of retrieving and/or consuming privately published NPM packages from the GitHub Package Registry. And neither of them is an exact match to your desired form, so here goes...

## OPTION 1.

You can consume the npm package directly within your application, provided you have a locally configured `.nprmc` file on your machine in your user directory
**AND**
you have created a GitHub [**personal access token**](https://github.com/settings/tokens) with the following scopes.

- repo: full (this is how you will be authenticated.)
- workflow
- write: packages
- adminOrg: read
- user: email

NOTE: You may not *require* all of these, but these are the permissions I used and had no issues. Once you generate the token, create or add it to your `.npmrc` file, replacing TOKEN with the actual token value.

```bash
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=TOKEN
```

Be sure to add the following snippet into the project or container within another `.npmrc` file in the root directory of the codebase.

```bash
@YOUR_GITHUB_USERNAME:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
```

---

## OPTION 2:

<<< BEGIN EDITS >>>

**NO LONGER AN OPTION!**

As [@nithin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1304645/nithin) has pointed out, this is no longer a viable option, which I confirmed before making this edit. (See screenshot) Additionally, [@th3s4mur41](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7041074/th3s4mur41) has [inquired about this](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/69687) on GitHub Discussions.

[image: see screenshot]

<<< END EDITS >>>

You can connect your package to a private GitHub repository, allowing you to access the `tar.gz` artifact for each package version and directly download it to your local machine from the web.

*GitHub > Your profile > Packages > Connect repository > Select and link*

[image: An npm package that has been published to the GitHub Package Registry AND linked to a GitHub repository will allow the owner to download the package artifacts as a .tar file.]

---

REFERENCE: *[How to publish packages to the GitHub Package Registry](https://dev.to/jgierer12/how-to-publish-packages-to-the-github-package-repository-4bai)*

Comment: Option 2 is not available now, right?

Comment: The feature seems to be gone for now...
Reported this as a bug: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/69687

Comment: It's less convenient than using the web UI, but you can use a request tool like Postman, curl, etc. to fetch the package metadata from https://npm.pkg.github.com/@org-name%2fpackage-name and then find the binary link from that output.  You'll need to include an "Authorization: Bearer <PAT>" header to authenticate those requests.