# Git clone all the repositories by bash script

Tags: git, github, git-clone

I have join a company and my company has GitHub account and It has 50 repositories I want to clone all the repositories in one go
Is there any way to clone all repositories by run bash script

```
https://github.com/CompanyName
```

Comment: Sure, you make a list of all repository names and then a bash script that iterates over that list. In each iteration you concatenate the full repository path to be cloned and do exactly that.

Comment: A simple google search revealed these among the first hits: https://bobbelderbos.com/2012/07/simple-bash-script-to-clone-remote-git-repositories/ and https://benito-zaragozi.com/snippets/clone-multiple-git-repositories-when-setting-up-your-ubuntu/

Comment: So I have to make repository name list. Is this possible by organisationName ?

Comment: You can't parse the web front end for the list, since it is paginated. You'll have to check if their API documentation shows an endpoint to retrieve such a list.

Comment: Seems this is the answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713596/how-to-retrieve-the-list-of-all-github-repositories-of-a-person

Answer (score -3):

## Create an array with the repositories:

```
arr=("repoa" "repob" "repoc")
```

## Create a for loop to clone all repos:

```
for i in ${0..49}; do git clone https://github.com/CompanyName/${arr[${i}]}; done
```

I would recommend using the repo tool with a designated manifest for your purpose.