# Find github username and repo

Tags: github, github-api

I have a field in which I have to write a GitHub username and a repository name and display the given repository of the given username which i entered in the field. What should be the URL of the request?

Comment: Do you mean: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#get-a-repository ?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8713596/9157799