# I want to retrieve the list of all GitHub repositories of which I am a team member

Tags: github

I'm part of a some big enterprise GitHub organizations and I'm member of a lot of different teams.

I would really like to see a list of repositories of which I'm part of a Team which have certain permissions on the repos? In your profile you only see your own private repositories, not the enterprise repositories you've access to.

### Example

Given the following organizations / teams / repos:

| Organization | Repository | Team |
| --- | --- | --- |
| org-1 | repo-1 | org-1/team-1 |
| org-1 | repo-2 | org-1/team-1 |
| org-1 | repo-3 | org-1/team-2 |
| org-1 | repo-4 | org-1/team-2 |
| org-2 | repo-5 | org-2/team-1 |
| org-2 | repo-6 | org-2/team-2 |
| org-2 | repo-7 | org-2/team-2 |
| org-2 | repo-8 | org-2/team-1 |

Assuming I'm part of `org-1/team-1` and `org-2/team-2`, I would want a list with only those repositories.

| Organization | Repository | Team |
| --- | --- | --- |
| org-1 | repo-1 | org-1/team-1 |
| org-1 | repo-2 | org-1/team-1 |
| org-2 | repo-6 | org-2/team-2 |
| org-2 | repo-7 | org-2/team-2 |

I've seen [How to retrieve the list of all GitHub repositories of a person?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713596/how-to-retrieve-the-list-of-all-github-repositories-of-a-person), but that's not taking teams into account.